# Find a matrix associated to the canonic basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am looking for confirmation on the following problem. If you notice any errors please let me know.

Let $L$: $R^2$ to $R^2$ be a linear transformation defined by.

$L(1,0)$ = $(1,0)$  and $L(1,1)$ = $(0,0)$

Find the matrix of $L$ associated to the canonic basis or $R^2$.

My work: In order to find the matrix $L$ associated to the canonic basis I will find the scalars

$(x,y)$ = $\alpha(1,0) + \beta(0,1)$. To this I then obtain $\alpha = x$ and $\beta = y$.

Now that I have my scalars I need to obtain my matrix by performing the following operations.

Then $[x,y]_C = (x,y)$

Now

$[1,0]_L$ = $(1,0)$;

$[1,1]_L$ = $(0,0)$;

Lastly place each transformation with respect to the scalars $(x,y)$.

Then our matrix is the following.

1    0

0    0

(I was unable to format the matrix).

Comment: You need to find $L(0,1)$, and for that you need to express $(0,1)$ as a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: I believe I have the wrong concept. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can check your own work: multiply $(1,1)$ by this matrix and compare this to the required result.

Answer (score 2):

The "canonical basis" for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbf{e_1} = (1,0), \mathbf{e_2} = (0,1)$. For our linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, we want a matrix $M_L$, where the columns of $M_L$ are the image of our basis vectors $\mathbf{e_1}, \mathbf{e_2}$, namely $L(\mathbf{e_1}), L(\mathbf{e_2})$.

We are given that $L(1,0) = (1,0)$. 
As $L$ is linear,
$$L(0,1) = L((1,1) - (1,0)) = L(1,1) - L(1,0) = (0,0) - (1,0) = (-1,0)$$
Thus our matrix $M_L$ is: $$M_L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
L(\mathbf{e_1}) & L(\mathbf{e_2}) \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
so that any vector $(x,y)$ under $L$ can be evaluated as:
$$L(x,y) 
= 
M_L*
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} * 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x - y \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$